# Cannot use nil as type _Ctype_CFAllocatorRef in argument to func literal

Tags: go, ethereum, solidity, go-ethereum

I'm running the command below to install a package for unit tests written in go for Solidity.

```
go install ./cmd/abigen
```

But I'm receiving these errors:

```
# github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/vendor/github.com/rjeczalik/notify
vendor/github.com/rjeczalik/notify/watcher_fsevents_cgo.go:51:216: cannot use nil as type _Ctype_CFAllocatorRef in argument to func literal
vendor/github.com/rjeczalik/notify/watcher_fsevents_cgo.go:165:47: cannot use nil as type _Ctype_CFAllocatorRef in argument to _Cfunc_CFStringCreateWithCStringNoCopy
vendor/github.com/rjeczalik/notify/watcher_fsevents_cgo.go:166:225: cannot use nil as type _Ctype_CFAllocatorRef in argument to func literal
```

Go version: go version go1.11.4 darwin/amd64

Comment: Looks like you did not install the c dependencies.

Comment: any luck or did the answer help?

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue as well.  The issue for me was the version of Geth vs Go I was using.  You likely need to upgrade geth to the current version or at least version geth v1.8.16

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/17751

That wasn't an option for me though, so I found a second solution.  In those lines of code, you will see nils, you do not need to switch all of them, but if you switch the ones specified to C.kCFAllocatorDefault it should work.  An example of the actual substitution is below.

51

```
var source = C.CFRunLoopSourceCreate(C.kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, &C.CFRunLoopSourceContext{
    perform: (C.CFRunLoopPerformCallBack)(C.gosource),
})
```

165

```
p := C.CFStringCreateWithCStringNoCopy(C.kCFAllocatorDefault, C.CString(s.path), C.kCFStringEncodingUTF8, C.kCFAllocatorDefault)
```

166

```
path := C.CFArrayCreate(C.kCFAllocatorDefault, (*unsafe.Pointer)(unsafe.Pointer(&p)), 1, nil)
```